# Targeting Users

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Normally I’d not bring up something like this, but there does seem to be a couple of users who are following the lead of a particular user who appears to be targeting other users who have disagreed with them in the past.  I had seen the behavior flagged before and had basically left it up to “the user is just trying to clean up some old answers which may be outdated” but more recent behavior lends itself more to actual targeting. To start, here is a picture of the latest post removal ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/31865749/1011527 ) :

[image: Targeting?]

The removal is not particularly notable by itself but note the 2 downvotes just prior to the removal. Why downvote if you plan to remove, and why 2 downvotes? Consider the circumstances: the answer has been out there for 5 years with no voting, then suddenly 2 votes within 2 minutes of each other and then the delete immediately thereafter. It suggests that this person doing the removal is colluding with someone to downvote (in the event the removal doesn’t go through). I have been part of other posts removed involving this particular user:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31745823/1011527
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/48175667/1011527
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/35183287/1011527
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/44272032/1011527

However, it doesn’t appear that downvoting was done, which is why I didn’t call attention to the action previously.

I understand that my concerns here are likely to fall of deaf ears, get me banned, and/or get me downvoted heavily. I am not really concerned with the artificial fake internet points but I have tried to be a good citizen of the community, save for one incident that some mod might bring up to prove otherwise.

Should targeting users be allowed in this manner? I suspect that unchecked this particular user may continue to look for and work with others to delete posts he thinks are not up to his quality standards, regardless of how satisfactory the answers might be.

Comment: This is best handled with a custom mod flag. Us mortals can't judge what targetting was done and by whom.

Comment: *Why downvote if you plan to remove* Voting to delete doesn't necessarily result in the post getting deleted. In case it doesn't get deleted, downvoting the answer is an indicator to other users and the one who posted the answer that the voter doesn't consider it useful to be on the site. Voting to close, voting to delete, and downvoting answers all at once doesn't seem unusual at all to me.

Comment: Note that questions cause by typos should be closed, not answered, and I'm sure there's a canonical for why one should avoid concatenating and use prepared statements.

Comment: @CertainPerformance consider the circumstances: the answer has been out there for 5 years with no voting, then suddenly 2 votes within 2 minutes of each other and then the delete immediately thereafter.

Comment: At least it appears as though nothing of value was lost

Comment: That's true @KevinB which is one reason why I hesitated to bring it up. However, I know this particular user has an issue with me and some others. I had also hesitated to bring that up because I've tried to play nice. C'est la vie I guess.

Comment: The downvotes in particular do look unnecessary to me, but, I can certainly understand and agree with the frustration of finding questions that should be deleted, but aren't because someone decided to answer them and the system thus prevents deletion due to the existence of said answer. I'd rather people be allowed to answer these, but it *not* prevent deletion by automatic means.

Comment: such cleaning operations come fairly regular, and so i loose some accepted answer post, but as i mostly respond to newbie questions, i take it there are dupes(how else can you  get rep anyway)

Comment: @JayBlanchard The only issue I personally have with you is that you have been rude towards me ever since I started participating more in PHP tag. I tend to avoid interactions with you for that reason. I don't know what other users you have in mind since I can't think of any.

Comment: None of those questions seem to be worth keeping around. I don't think this "evidence" demonstrates what you appear to think it does.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to delete are in no way contradictory. That makes no sense as an argument.

Comment: If we agree the content needed to go anyway, what are we discussing?

Comment: You voted to close the question you linked to. Considering that, why did you answer it? And why do you object to it being deleted?

Comment: @TylerH I don't object to it being deleted, I object to the manner in which it was deleted. I guess it is wrong of me to object to some things. Can some mod do me the favor of deleting this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard What manner of deletion would you consider unobjectionable? It seems like there's only one manner in which users can delete questions: vote to delete, so I'm not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: @TylerH I think the "manner" is the downvote prior to the deletion, quoting "suddenly 2 votes within 2 minutes of each other and then the delete immediately thereafter".

Comment: @Scratte What's the issue with downvoting content you think is bad/delete-worthy? If you think a question is delete-worthy you should always downvote it as well.

Comment: @TylerH While I completely agree with you, and I see no issue with the downvotes on this case: the delete votes were cast on the **question**, and the OP is mostly complaining about downvotes on their **answer**.

Comment: @TylerH I do not think I *should* downvote anything. Just as I *should* also not upvote anything. It's my choice, no? I don't downvote everything I think should be deleted. Some posts are made in good faith and I do not feel any urge to downvote something that is going to be deleted anyway. I prefer downvoting the posts that will stay visible. Also, votes disappear from my profile when the post is removed, which is really rather irritating.

Comment: @yivi But I downvoted the answer as it contained mistakes. Executing that code produces errors (there's a missing mandatory parameter in `mysqli_error()`). Why should I not downvote it? I assume whoever else downvoted it also had a similar train of thought. I was the first to vote to delete the question which means I had no guarantee that there would be 2 other users willing to delete it too. In this case, a downvote on a wrong answer is justified in my opinion.

Comment: @Dharman I haven't argued against the downvotes, I was just responding to Tyler's comment because I thought there was a mistake there. I agree with _"If you think a question is delete-worthy you should always downvote it as well"_, but the OP didn't post a question, that's all. I don't think you should justify your votes in any way.

Answer (score 21):

What makes you think you were targeted?

It seems the question is about me. I don't pay much attention to users who posted an answer or a question. I don't recall the question you mention in particular. I never asked anyone to downvote it either.

I have deleted a lot of unnecessary old PHP posts. I agree some of them might have had your answers, but I was never aiming to target you. If it happened that I voted twice in one day on your post it's very likely a coincidence or posts were linked in some way (e.g. related posts). I assume other users must have also noticed some reputation drop due to their deleted answers, but I don't target any users.

There are users both in the 10K+ tools and in SOCVR who help with the deletion. Only deletion. However, each user must evaluate the post they vote on themselves. Some posts I voted to delete never got the other 2 votes, which is also fine.

I am only downvoting posts that I think have no value. This means that **I usually downvote posts that I believe should be deleted.** This is a signal to other people who will review the post later, that neither the question nor answers are very useful. I don't always downvote answers, but most of the time I downvote both the question and all answers. If there are good answers then there is probably no reason to delete the question, although this does not always apply. With duplicates, the answers might be good, but the question has already been asked hundreds of times and the question can be deleted without downvoting answers.

I have so far voted to delete almost 2500 questions. How many of these questions had your answer? Statistically, I would guess that a number of them must have had.

I am also regularly on the [first page of top voters](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=month) and I mostly downvote. How many of these votes were on your posts? Hard to say, but statistically, there must have been some.

Reputation loss from downvotes is usually reversed after the post gets deleted, so my downvotes should not have a negative long-term effect on your reputation.

It's good that you care about the content, and if you think that I voted to delete something that was a very useful question then you can request on Meta a review of such deletion. But please do not accuse me of targetted downvoting on your posts.

Comment: Sorry but I don't buy it. Plus, I even pinged you a few times in others questions and never once did you respond. So please, don't take me/us for a fool.

Comment: Quote: "How do you find any good questions to answer in PHP? I can't find anything interesting."  Users do tend to lose interest in a topic over time, natural progression and all.  But rather best to leave it to people that still can.  Very easy to do, just add [php] to the Ignored Tags section of your profile.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't recall any pings from you. Can you give an example?

Comment: @HansPassant ignoring tags works cool for folks using this site just for fun (answers, rep points etc). For those who rely on it in their job, not so well. "Sorry boss, I completed this task 10x slower than usual because related SO tag turned out to be polluted by useless noise dumped by help vampires and rep hunters"

Answer (score 13):

Not withstanding that *two* of your four example questions were closed as duplicates, the other two questions either lack debugging details or lack explanation as to what's going on with the code.  And no, "doesn't show results" isn't quite good enough as an explanation as to what's going on.

The only compelling argument you seem to be making here is that the questions you answered were all deleted by the same user.  To me, that's not enough to say that you're being targeted, or that you're being somehow judged based on you, yourself, or your personal methodology of answering questions.

Since all of these questions are fairly old, and none of them [hit the 3 vote threshold for you to keep the rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248), you're basically out 70 reputation.  You've essentially made that rep back this month.

(It *does* look like you got the short end of the stick [on a particularly nasty vote reversal though](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard?tab=reputation&sort=time), so that's unfortunate.  Not much I can say on that, since there's not much in the way of details that I know.)

Comment: Please do not bring dirty laundry out. It's not appropriate to mention the question asker's reputation gain or loss unless it is directly related to the topic.

Comment: @Dharman:  In my experience, I can't see any other real reason to complain about "being targeted" *besides* reputation. That's how one finds out about it.  It's also not "dirty laundry"; their reputation loss or gain is not a secret since it's visible on their reputation chart.  My hypothesis is that there's something going on here that caused them to lose a huge chunk of rep, and then they're seeing *more* posts deleted on top of that, which is what's boiling over into a theory of them being targeted.  It's an angle, and I'll submit if it's the *wrong* angle, I'd be happy to revise my stance.

Comment: @Makoto you can reverse your stance. One does not have anything to do with the other.

Comment: Okay @JayBlanchard; my stance no longer includes a theory about the voting reversal having to do with this circumstance of you believing you're targeted.  I'll submit it was a bit out in left field.  However, the circumstances around reputation gain/loss still apply since this is probably the only way you learned about this.

Comment: You're correct @Makoto in as much as that is how I learned about it.

Answer (score 7):

> *Should targeting users be allowed in this manner?*

I don't understand this! No two of the five deleted questions you linked were asked by the same user - so where is the targeting? These question were found and selected for *possible* deletion (remember, it takes at least three 'ordinary' delete votes) based solely on their lack of usefulness.

A quick survey of the "other two" delete voters on those questions suggests to me (though I have no hard evidence) that they resulted from `[del-pls]` requests in the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Now, although the activities of that room are, from time-to-time, raised on Meta (for various reasons), as a regular visitor to it (some might even call me a *resident*), I can assure you that the Room Owners (two of whom are Diamond Moderators) are *very vigilant* in stamping-out **any form of user-targeting** in terms of requests for close- or delete-votes.

> *Why downvote if you plan to remove, and why 2 downvotes?*

A post with a net negative score can be deleted more easily; and, in some cases (not especially relevant here) more quickly. However, in terms of reputation loss to the poster of the deleted question: there is none, if the post is deleted. Furthermore, any reputation gained from **good** (net scores >= +3) answers to deleted question will also not be lost.

Answer (score -17):

This is way too long for a comment.

I too feel that I have been targeted and this started back in August 2020. I feel the leading person has a bone to pick with me and other members that I yes, I call "friends".

This guy is even friends with another member who hates my guts, so I can "do the math".

I even asked a moderator to ping me to see all of the questions/answers that were deleted by the same person, but all I got was the same pasted message of them being declined.

NOTA: The links below can only be seen by 10k+ members and moderators.

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/28757416/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/25982376/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/35183287/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31089460/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/39960182/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/19200663/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/26518385/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/26745811/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24917747/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/27450999/

I don't recall doing a cleanup. I recall that a **deleting rampage** with perfectly good questions and answer(s).

Some of which were also downvoted and then deleted.

On a final edit note: I won't be responding to comments. I've said my piece.

Comment: all but one of those "perfectly good questions" were closed more than 3 years ago.

Comment: I am not friends with anyone on the site. I don't know your friends either. I have no bone to pick with you, I always valued your hard work and I really appreciate it. You are really good at closing questions and I think you should keep it up.

Comment: None of those questions seem to be worth keeping around. I don't think this "evidence" demonstrates what you appear to think it does.

Comment: Among the questions you have listed I only see one duplicate closure, which doesn't look like a useful signpost. Some of them were deleted by me and a moderator. Closed question should be deleted. If they should not be deleted then why are they closed? Maybe they should get reopened?

Comment: @Dharman I do not agree that closed Questions should be deleted. If that was the case, there's be no reason to limit Roomba to certain metrics. If a post is poor, misleading, useless or redundant, it's another matter. Closed just isn't enough.

Comment: @Scratte We can't let the system delete everything automatically, if a post has positively-scoring answers or an accepted answer then there should be a manual review. Maybe there is a way to edit the question and answers and improve it enough so that the deletion is not warranted. Some closed posts are useful, but that is rather a minority. e.g. Some typos are common and having a good explanation how to spot them might be useful even though we do not accepts such questions in general.

Comment: "*On a final edit note: I won't be responding to comments, I've said my piece.*" It seems hypocritical to [call out a user for allegedly not responding to comment pings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402402/targeting-users#comment804671_402404) and then take this stance.

Comment: Also, I'm again really perplexed that in several cases you're complaining about questions that *you* have voted to close. Are you also being targeted by yourself?

Comment: As the moderator that handled your flags: I gave you a personal decline note. However, you had raised *three* flags, so I did indeed copy my first decline message to the other two flags; there wasn’t anything else to say. I can understand you didn’t like the outcome but your insinuation that you got a canned response is not appreciated. Please be aware moderators are *volunteers* and I spent quite some time investigating the situation, and so did a CM I had asked to assist. The flags were taken seriously, but in the end had no merit.

Comment: As for not pinging you: our moderator tools let me pull up a list of deleted posts trivially, there was no need to ask you for such a list.

Comment: @Scratte the reason the roomba is limited to a certain set of criteria is because *within those criteria* we can trust a bot to do the deleting, without human intervention. Do not take those parameters as anything more than that, they are deliberately strict to reduce the chances of false positives, and there is plenty of scope for humans to make additional judgement calls about the value of posts that fall outside of those narrow bounds.

Comment: Tip: always save the links of your meta posts. They will be likely soon deleted. I suggest also to not leaving comments entirely out, the community needs a clear feedback if it is going on the bad way.

Comment: @peterh This user appears to be temporarily suspended now, but otherwise have more than enough reputation to be able to find their own deleted posts. (`deleted:1 user:me`). The advise seems to be redundant on this particular post.